# How to mock user creation if password is hidden in Laravel 5.5 unit tests

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, passwords

I have a unit acceptance test where I am mocking the creation of a user.

```
class UserAcceptanceApiTest extends TestCase
{
    use WithoutMiddleware;

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->User = factory(App\Models\User::class)->make([
            'id' => '999',
            'name' => 'Name',
            'email' => 'test@example.com',
            'password' => bcrypt('password'),
        ]);
        $this->User = factory(App\Models\User::class)->make([
            'id' => '999',
            'name' => 'Name',
            'email' => 'test@example.com',
            'password' => bcrypt('password'),
        ]);
        $user = factory(App\Models\User::class)->make();
        $this->actor = $this->actingAs($user);
    }



    public function testStore()
    {
        $response = $this->actor->call('POST', 'api/users', $this->User->toArray());
        $this->assertEquals(200, $response->getStatusCode());
        $this->seeJson(['id' => 999]);
    }

}
```

I get the following exception `"Field 'password' doesn't have a default value`.

This is because in my `User` model I have the following:

```
protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];
```

So it automatically removes the password field from the JSON.

**Is there a way I can override this only for this test?** As I want to keep the password as a hidden attribute.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public function testStore()
{
    $this->User->makeVisible(['password']);
    $response = $this->actor->call('POST', 'api/users', $this->User->toArray());
    $this->assertEquals(200, $response->getStatusCode());
    $this->seeJson(['id' => 999]);
}
```